# Is Parse.com's hasPrefix considered a regex?

Tags: regex, parse-platform

Does hasPrefix count against the 80 req/min limit of regular expressions?

Comment: If you're referring to [`whereKey:hasPrefix`](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#/c:objc(cs)PFQuery(im)whereKey:hasPrefix:), then I would assume no, as it's matching an exact substring rather than a pattern. Though, you may consider [contacting those are Parse](http://parse.com/help) to clarify (note the "Contact us" link in the middle of the page).

Comment: Thanks. The documentation isn't clear and the "Contact us" link is broken. I'll try again later. I guess I could just test it and see if it throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

Parse confirmed that whereKey:hasPrefix does count against the 80 req/min limit of regex.

Comment: If you could site the source, I'm sure it'd be hugely beneficial for others that come across this question :)